# Forcing a string to break in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar made up of items in an unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

But they would look better displayed as

```
Item<br>
1
```

With a forced break in between `Item` and `1`

Edit: `width` is 190px.

I can't use HTML to add a `<br>` tag. Ideally, I was looking for a way to do it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your markup looks like this then:

```
<ul>

    <li><span class="title">Item</span> <span class="number">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Item</span> <span class="number">2</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Item</span> <span class="number">2</span></li>

</ul>
```

Then what you have to do is get each `<span>` on its own row. It's simple.

```
.title, .number {
    display: block;
}
```

Since each `<span>` now is a block, they will take the full width of the container as default.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with css only (if you can't change the mark up). You can only make the *ul* have a small width and force the number on the next line that way. But then the text would have to be equally long for all items.

You can do it with javacript however. Either by wrapping the text and number in tags with display block - or adding a `<br>` tag in between.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `word-spacing`. Obviously 190 pixels corresponds to the parent width value. You can also give it a higher value so that the word coming after will never have enough place and force the *line break* to happen.

Something like this:

```
li {
  word-spacing: 190px;
}
```

Not sure if there is another way to achieve this without changing the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a small width on the `li` elements, effectively forcing line wrapping. If the content is really “Item 1” etc., or generally two words, you can set a very small width, forcing each word on a line of its own, e.g.:

```
li { width: 1em; }
```

However, I cannot see a reason why such rendering would be an improvement, and I suspect the real problem is somewhat different.